# Specific SQLState handling in ajax error return

Tags: javascript, sql, error-handling

I have an ajax block that posts to an insert function, which works, but in the instance of a duplicate key error I'm trying to handle the code more specifically

With `data` containing the POST info:

```
type: "POST",
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    location.reload();
  },
  error: function (jqxhr, status, exception) {
    alert("Exception:", exception);
  },
```

So otherwise, it inserts and refreshes the page as normal. But if the record exists on the unique key, then the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: -803 [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0803 - Duplicate key value specified
```

Is there a preferred way to grab that specific code, and if that is the present code then change my alert message accordingly?

Comment: You want to catch that server error and either return some 4## error code to your front end that knows what to do with the error, or return a 200 with a message informing about the error, and your success method would have to check for that before reloading.  The difference between the two is if you have a strong opinion about how HTTP response codes should be defined in a REST context.

Comment: That does make sense, and I want to eventually handle more errors specifically from the database. But in this sense, I get an exception popup from JS and once I click OK then I get the sqlstate error in my inspector. I would just like to be able to check that sqlstate code and say 'if code is this, then tell user it exists' etc.

Comment: Then that would lean more towards catching the error on the server, and returns a 200 with a message that the success interrogates and handles.

Comment: So as a temporary measure, is there no way I can specify the -803 code in this alert for now? Is there a place in the jqXHR object that will have that, or is it stopping at the 500 level?

Comment: Is that secondary snippet what is alerting currently if there is an error?

Comment: Yes, that shows in the network area of the console once I clear the exception. I think only because the exception in JS halts the inspector from loading yet but it seems it would be part of the jqXHR object

Comment: Then at a bare minimum you could do an `indexOf(' -803 ')` on the exception to see if that is a substring of the message, and handle accordingly.